# Union of Struct inside a Struct - mixing C and C++

Tags: c++, c, esp32

I am not that familiar with C programming, and try to port/mix some code from C into a C++ project for an embedded device called ESP32 (Compiling with c99 and using gcc). The libraries are mostly C, and I know that this can cause some challenges. The struct is defined in a .h file, and I try to initialize the struct in a cpp file.

I encountered an issue when I found a struct, containing an unnamed union of structs. 
The logic seem to be fairly straightforward :

```
typedef struct{
i2c_mode_t mode;      
gpio_num_t sda_io_num;        
gpio_pullup_t sda_pullup_en;  
gpio_num_t scl_io_num;      
gpio_pullup_t scl_pullup_en; 

union{

    struct {
        uint32_t clk_speed;    
    } master;
    struct {
        uint8_t addr_10bit_en;  
        uint16_t slave_addr;   
    } slave;
};

}i2c_config_t;
```

When trying to access its members through initialising the struct, it complains :

*"a designator for an anonymous union member can only appear within braces corresponding to that anonymous union"*

```
i2c_config_t conf = {
    .mode = I2C_MODE_MASTER,
    .sda_io_num = i2c_gpio_sda,
    .sda_pullup_en = GPIO_PULLUP_ENABLE,
    .scl_io_num = i2c_gpio_scl,
    .scl_pullup_en = GPIO_PULLUP_ENABLE,
    .master.clk_speed = i2c_frequency
};
```

This is probably some elementary and simple solution, but it would be great to know what is causing this.

The assumption is that when I place the initializer in a CPP file, the complaining starts, and I probably need to use standard C++ when initializing the struct.

But how do you do this on the structs inside the unnamed union?

Comment: Not related to the compiler error, that's a wildly fishy union. Consider using separate variables instead.

Comment: I'm concerned about the fact that the bits don't match up. Why are you using a union on both a 32-bit struct and a 24-bit struct? This is a memory leak/bug waiting to happen

Comment: Long story short: Arduino is just a major burden here, try to make a clean C project and all problems will go away.

Comment: I am not sure if the entire struct is dumped to the device. I assume the values are put into use in a bigger entity before its written to the device.

Comment: Arduino is not used.... we are using the library from the device vendor. C++ should work nicely, since we have tested several implementations already.

Comment: So compile it as C then, problem solved.

Comment: compile file containg this code as C and use it in other C++ files.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the last comment. I am not a professional programmer. The compiler is c99, using gcc. If I replace .mode = I2C_MODE_MASTER, with I2C_MODE_MASTER, it works. But how is it done when I get to the unnamed union? Do I need some brackets or something?

Comment: why not adding a name to this anonymous union ?

Comment: This is just wild guessing .... and trial and error : i2c_config_t* i2c_conf;  i2c_conf->master.clk_speed = i2c_frequency; And it compiled without errors ..... but is this correct? Is this the answer?

Comment: The `.identifier`-syntax is C-only right now (I think it is added in C++20), so for standard c++ you have to remove them all. For the union, you have to write `{i2c_frequency}`, this aggregates initializes the struct `master`. You cannot initialize slave directly, since in C++ one can only directly intialize the first member of a union. (Of course you can later change the active member)

Comment: It is really stupid that I did not try that ... this seem to work

Answer (score -2):

.master = {100000}  // online first union can be set in c++